# Как создать страницу ошибки 404 в Yii2-advanced?

Tags: yii2, http-status-code-404

Если набрать URL вида http://site.com/blog/blogblogyjr , где blogblogyir- несуществующая страница сайта site.com/blog, то вместо страницы 404 появляется это:
[image]

Сам файл NotFoundHttpException находиться: D:\sites\site\yii2\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\web

код из BlogController.php (находится в dir: D:\sites\site\yii2\frontend\controllers)

```
<?php

namespace frontend\controllers;


use common\models\Blog;
use Yii;
use yii\web\Controller;

/**
 * Blog controller
 */
class BlogController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Displays homepage.
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function actionIndex()
    {
        #$blogs = Blog::find()->where(['status_id'=>1])->orderBy(['id' => SORT_DESC])->all();

       $blogs = Blog::find()->andWhere(['status_id'=>1])->orderBy('sort')->all();
        #$blogs = Blog::find()->where(['status_id'=>1])->orderBy(['id' => SORT_ASC])->all();
        return $this->render('all',['blogs'=>$blogs]);
    }

       public function actionOne($url)
    {  
       if($blog = Blog::find()->andWhere(['url'=>$url])->one()) {
            return $this->render('one',['blog'=>$blog]);
      }
       throw new NotFoundHttpException ();
    }


}
```

помогло указание в BlogController - use yii\web\NotFoundHttpException;
но как сделать, чтобы заработало сообщение  в строке BlogController throw new NotFoundHttpException ('ой,нет такого блога'); сейчас просто выводится Not Found (#404) page not found

Comment: Вы должны подключить пространство имен, где лежит NotFoundHttpException или напрямую его вызвать yii\web\NotFoundHttpException также в конфиге надо errorHandler сконфигурировать

Comment: помогло указание в BlogController - use NotFoundHttpException; 2 способ не совсем понятен: ErrorHandler есть в той же папке, что и NotFoundHttpException -D:\sites\site\yii2\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\web  как его сконфигурировать и вызвать напрямую можно?

Comment: Папка и пространство имен не одно и тоже. Есть PSR, согласно кооторому рекомендуется адресацию нэймспэйсов и каталогов делать одинаковыми там, где лежит сам класс. Изучите подробнее как работают Namespace в PHP

Answer (score 3):

Можете указать action, в котором будут обрабатываться ошибки:

```
...
'errorHandler' => [
    'errorAction' => 'site/error',
],
...
```

И в контроллере SiteController добавить что-то подобное:

```
public function actionError()
{
    $exception = Yii::$app->errorHandler->exception;
    if ($exception !== null) {
        if ($exception->statusCode == 404)
            return $this->render('error404', ['exception' => $exception]);
        else
            return $this->render('error', ['exception' => $exception]);
    }
}
```

Создать представление error404 и выводить там все что душе угодно.

Ссылка на документацию: https://nix-tips.ru/yii2-api-guides/guide-ru-runtime-handling-errors.html

Answer (score 2):

`frontend/config/local-web.php` (какой-то такой)

```
...
'errorHandler' => [
    'errorRoute' => 'site/error',
    ...
],
...
```

`frontend/views/site/error.php`

```
<?php
echo 'custom template';
?>
```

Где дефолтный темплейт для перепила - наверно, не подскажу.